# How can I apply my form to multiple templates in django

Tags: django, forms, inclusion

I am creating a blog site where users can post articles on the home page which can then also be commented on using a form. These posts can also be viewed elsewhere on the site, under search results and on user profiles for example. What I am trying to do is allow users to comment on the posts anywhere that they appear. For this I am using an inclusion tag for my comment form which looks like this:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('posts/comment.html')
def comment_create_and_list_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    c_form = CommentModelForm()

    if 'submit_c_form' in request.POST:
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            instance = c_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
            instance.save()
            c_form = CommentModelForm()

    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'c_form': c_form,
    }

    return context
```

And is registered to my urls like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .templatetags.custom_tags import comment_create_and_list_view
from .views import *

app_name = 'posts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('comment/<int:pk>/', comment_create_and_list_view, name='comment'),
]
```

My form looks like this:

```
class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body',)
```

comment.html looks like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'posts:comment' post.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value={{ post.id }}>
    {{ c_form }}
    <button type="submit" name="submit_c_form">Send</button>
</form>
```

And I am importing the inclusion tag to my base.html file using `{% comment_create_and_list_view request %}`

Upon attempting to load the page I receive the NoReverseMatch at / error:

`Reverse for 'comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']`

Been googling this for hours and can't understand where I am going wrong...

Comment: you can use actions in form

Comment: Thank you, you're right I had forgotten to do that. I have edited my question. However my form is still not being shown

Comment: you can use templatetags

Comment: Can you please evaluate? How can I use templatetags for this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: Thanks, you have put me on the right track, although another issue is plaguing me now... Question edited again

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else someday, I fixed my problem by refactoring my inclusion tag to only render the form:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('posts/comment.html')
def comment_tag():
    c_form = CommentModelForm()

    return {'c_form': c_form}
```

And added a view to handle submissions:

```
def comment_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if 'submit_c_form' in request.POST:
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            instance = c_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
            instance.save()

    return redirect('posts:index')
```

I then adjusted comment.html to simply apply the form with `{{ c_form }}` and wrapped my template tag with the form element in my index:

```
<form action="{% url 'posts:comment' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input typ="hidden" name="post_id" value={{ post.id }}>
    {% comment_tag %}
    <button type="submit" name="submit_c_form">Send</button>
</form>
```